# How to change the order of the users on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, multi-user

I have setup a tablet for my 2yo son. I am the primary user, with root access, etc. Because of this, I am the first user on the lock screen. I would prefer if the tablet defaulted to *his* user account, so he doesn't have to click the tiny user button to get his login on power up. Does anyone know how?

I tried altering the order of users inside /data/system/users/userlist.xml, but it reverted back to the original file on reboot.

The tablet is running Android 4.2.2.